# Merge all files (CSS, JS, HTML) to one HTML with Grunt

Tags: angularjs, merge, gruntjs, concatenation

I have a specific project where all of the code (CSS, JS (Angular), HTML) must be in one giant HTML. I could manually copy all CSS and JS to `index.hml` but it is time consuming and prone to errors.

For some project I already use Grunt, so I was trying to use `grunt-contrib-concat` but it only merges files one under another. This doesn't really helps me, because the CSS should be in the `sytle` section in the header of the HTML, JS in the script section.

I read help on the [github](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) page, but there is no obvious solution.

I call the `contac` function like this:

```
 concat: {
    options: {
      separator: ';',
    },
    dist: {
      src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html', '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/main.css', '<%= yeoman.app %>scripts/outro.js'],
      dest: 'dist/index.html',
    }
  }
```

This is only a test, and the result is not good for me.

Are here any place holders to tell the concat where to insert specific files?

Comment: May I ask why you need to do this?

Comment: We have and old program written in Delphi... Slowly we are moving our application to the web. Some new functionality we wish to use in Delphi and on the web. So now our delphi application would replace some ids in this html file and opens the page. The easiest way is to merge everything in to one file. The online version has files broken down - like it should be.

Comment: I don't envy you, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In grunt we have a plugin

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
```

This plugin concats all files which you specify.